# C++ Won't Install in Netbeans 11.0

Tags: c++, netbeans-plugins

I'm a beginner at programming and would like to know more about C++. I installed Netbeans since it says it supports Java (which I am currently studying the basics at school) and C++ (which I want to study for personal interest). But when I tried to create a new project, I can't find C++. So I followed tutorials and ended up trying to install the plugin. The thing is, it is not successful for me. A message says:

"The Plugin Installer found problem timeout of loading C/C++ Remote Development API[org.netbeans.modules.cnd.api.remote/1.29.5.1] while install the following plugins: C/C++"

JDK version:
java version "14.0.2"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)

NetBeans version:
Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-404-on-20190319)

Windows 10

Any recommendation/solution for me to both run Java and C++ on Netbeans? Thank you!

Comment: Eclipse can run both Java and C++. I wouldn't recommend it however. Since C++ is for your own personal interest why not install one of the many free specialist C++ IDEs. Visual Studio Community Edition would be my recommendation. More lightweight options also exist, if that is a concern.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If there's no chance for me to do both coding in one IDE, I'll definitely take a look in VS.

Comment: When looking for an IDE, I'm a fan of the ones that [eat their own dog food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food). There's nothing more annoying than an IDE that works perfectly for the language it was written in and less-so for other supported languages. Obviously the writers of the IDE found and fixed a lot of bugs and usability issues while writing the IDE and it shows. And then along comes the C++ plug in that clearly didn't get the same level of care and feeding and then... Then... Hulk SMASH puny IDE!

Comment: If you want to learn cpp I would strongly advice you to first learn how to compile and link programs on the command line (e.g `gcc` or `clang`) before turning to IDEs. Im convinced that this will strongly boost your understanding about what is really going on. This is completely sufficient for small toy projects anyways.

Comment: For me Netbeans + "C/C++ plugin" is the best combination for C/C++, it's fastest and lightweight than Eclipse, and suitable for projects relying on special scripts for compilations (VSCode can't put up with projects like that).

Comment: I have been using Netbeans 11 (11.2 and 11.3) with C/C++ plugin since the beginning of those releases, But I'm having the same problem as you with Netbeans 12, guessed right now if it had something related to Java 14 as you are using it with Netbeans 11 and that's what I have new in my environment besides Netbeans 12, but I didn't get success changing it from Java 14 to 11 (or 8).

Answer (score 2):

It did work for me downgrading the default Java from version 14 to version 11.

After having commented somewhere above my unsuccessful experience like yours. I decided to try it again but now focusing on Java version. I realized that Java version was the common point between your and mine environment. You tried Netbeans 11 but I the recent version 12, and I had successful experiences in the past using C/C++ plugin with versions 11.1, 11.2 and 11.3 of Netbeans.

I didn't go deeper to answer why it worked with Java 11 and not with 14. However, I can't believe it is the JVM version purely.

Later, after the installation I changed it again to Java 14, and it's still working. Below is the output terminal:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/bin/java          1091      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle/bin/java          1091      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode

$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)

$ /media/sf_downloads/Apache-NetBeans-12.0-bin-linux-x64.sh
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...

$ sudo update-alternatives --config java   
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-oracle/bin/java          1091      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle/bin/java          1091      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-oracle/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode

$ java --version
java 14.0.2 2020-07-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**My Linux version:**

```
$ uname -a
Linux devmint 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**The plugin appears as: "User Installed Plugin"**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Experienced this problem with Netbeans 12. As experiment installed 11 but in the install dialog for the location and Java selection I didn't allow the JDK 15. I selected the current default Java 11. The C++ install worked.

Uninstalled 12 and reinstalled with changing to default Java. It installed C++ fine and works okay.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate what you mean in actual detail, by "with changing default Java' phrase, as I also have RH/CentOS 8 problem installing C/C++ plugin on NB IDE 12.0:  with a timeout on [org.netbeans.modules.cnd.api.remote/1.29.5.1]

Comment: OK Never mind, found the details here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4452