# The Plugin Installer found problem timeout of loading C/C++ Remote Development API

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, plugins, cygwin

I have installed java 15.0.1 and netbeans 12.0. I have also installed cygwin64 compiler.
While installing c/c++ plugins received error:
The Plugin Installer found problem timeout of loading C/C++ Remote Development API[org.netbeans.modules.cnd.api.remote/1.29.5.1] while install the following plugins: c/c++

I want to execute c program in netbeans is there any solution available?

Comment: did you try to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047487/c-wont-install-in-netbeans-11-0

Comment: Same for me on NB 12.0